# flutter updating dependency error || version issues (pubspec.yaml) || upgrade flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, build, dependencies, upgrade

I used this **flutter upgrade** command for upgrade flutter and after **upgrade** the flutter I got some issue's(version issues in pubspec.yaml file) and after resolving it I got this error.

Help to solve this. I dint have any idea why this error is coming so please suggest me some ideas for resolving this issue.

**EORR**:-

```
/C:/Users/sonal/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/time_picker_widget-1.0.0+10/lib/time_picker_widget.dart:1377:33: Error: The getter 'accentTextTheme' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'.
 - 'ThemeData' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'accentTextTheme'.
            _buildMinutes(theme.accentTextTheme, secondaryLabelColor);
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1201

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 50s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: demo
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none'

version: 2.0.8

environment:
#  sdk: '>=1.23.0 <3.0.0'
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  fluttertoast:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  http:
#  charts_flutter:
  font_awesome_flutter:
  shared_preferences:
  fl_chart: ^0.55.1
  gauges:
  line_chart:
  syncfusion_flutter_gauges:
  intro_slider: ^3.0.10
  lazy_load_scrollview:
  url_launcher:
  percent_indicator:
  syncfusion_flutter_charts:
  dropdown_search: ^2.0.1
  intl:
  syncfusion_flutter_datepicker:
  im_stepper:
  lottie:
  multi_select_flutter:
  getwidget:
  month_picker_dialog: ^2.0.2
  image_picker:
  image_cropper:
  dropdown_plus:
  flutter_typeahead:
  searchfield: ^0.5.6
  easy_audio_player:
  flutter_countdown_timer:
  time_picker_widget: ^1.0.0+10
#  time_range_picker: ^2.2.0
  directed_graph:
  graphite:
  graphview:
  flutter_svg: ^1.1.6
  flutter_html_all: ^3.0.0-alpha.5
  random_avatar: ^0.0.7
  pull_to_refresh:
  basic_utils:
  random_color: ^1.0.6-nullsafety
  platform_info: ^3.2.0
  cuberto_bottom_bar: ^2.0.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.1.1
  internet_connection_checker: ^0.0.1+4
  liquid_swipe: ^3.0.0
  flutter_advanced_drawer: ^1.3.2
  glassmorphism: ^3.0.0
  filter_list: ^1.0.2
  fl_location: ^1.2.2
  fl_location_platform_interface: ^1.1.1
  easy_localization: ^3.0.1
  pie_chart: ^5.3.2



flutter_icons:
  image_path: "android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png"
  android: true
  ios: true

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  change_app_package_name:
  flutter_launcher_icons:

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/
    
  fonts:
    - family: Montserrat-Regular
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf
```

Answer (score 0):

I really think that this lib `time_picker_widget-1.0.0+10` isn't prepared to work with the newest Flutter versions.

The first error means that the Type expected on the first argument of `_buildMinutes` method isn't the same as `theme.accentTextTheme` check both types to see if they're the same. I would probably investigate if ThemeData had some changes that didn't allow you to get this data like this.

The other point is that you could use Time Picker libs that are more reliable. This one has very bad maintenance. Consider to use libs that are highly recommended and you can see clearly that the owners care about and at least update their libs. In a fast search around [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages?q=time%20picker) I found:

- date_picker_timeline
- day_night_time_picker